# What is the meaning of "therefore all died" in 2 Corinthians 5:14?

Tags: 2-corinthians, atonement

> 2 Corinthians 5:14 For Christ's love compels us, because we are convinced that one died for all, and therefore all died.

What is the logic here? What is the meaning of the word "therefore"?

Who are the "all"?

> John 14:19 Because I live, you also will live.

> 2 Corinthians 4:10 We always carry around in our body the death of Jesus, so that the life of Jesus may also be revealed in our body.

Jesus lives, therefore you live.
Jesus died for all, therefore all died.

Comment: Closed and migrated as user is no longer active on the platform and the original question was a duplicate, even though the original question is less active