# Have we already escaped the corruption that is in the world?

Tags: greek, 2-peter

2Pe 1:4 BSB Through these He has given us His precious and magnificent promises, so that through them you may become partakers of the divine nature, now that you have escaped the corruption in the world caused by evil desires.

2Pe 1:4 ISV Through these he has given us his precious and wonderful promises, so that through them you may participate in the divine nature, seeing that you have escaped the corruption that is in the world caused by evil desires

2Pe 1:4 NET Through these things he has bestowed on us his precious and most magnificent promises, so that by means of what was promised you may become partakers of the divine nature, after escaping the worldly corruption that is produced by evil desire.

2Pe 1:4 KJV Whereby are given unto us exceeding great and precious promises: that by these ye might be partakers of the divine nature, having escaped the corruption that is in the world through lust.

How do we understand the words "having escaped".

And how does it shape the meaning of the verse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> His (God's) divine power has granted to us everything pertaining to life and godliness, through the true knowledge of Him who called us by His own glory and excellence. 4Through these He has granted to us His precious and magnificent promises, so that by them you may become partakers of the divine nature, having escaped the corruption that is in the world on account of lust. 2Pet 1:3-4

Being in Christ has separated us from the enslavement of/to the world.
we have the contrast set up to see -

- become partakers of the divine nature,
- having escaped the corruption that is in the world

Two kingdoms, two kings, two reasons for living. Once we are called out of the world, we are to practise being citizens of the new Kingdom and remember that we are not without a choice. We did not have a choice when we were slaves. If we are of Christ, we have a choice - we should exercise it.

> Therefore, brothers and sisters, be all the more diligent to make certain about His calling and choice of you; for as long as you practice these things, you will never stumble; 11for in this way the entrance into the eternal kingdom of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ will be abundantly supplied to you. 2Pet 1:10

We have *escaped* because we were set free - just as the Israelites were set free - being allowed to *escape* from Egypt, they now were offered a choice - to worship and obey God. Believers are also offered this choice.

The world is a realm of destruction and death - there is no life, no light, no hope, no purpose. It is corrupted to the very core and is irredeemable. *Except* for being removed from darkness and deceit and shown the light and the truth.

> He has rescued us from the **dominion of darkness** and brought us into the kingdom of His beloved Son Col 1:13

The meaning of *escape* is not to be aligned with a peaceful managed exit. We are to flee when given the chance. To take nothing with us. The Israelites wanted to go back to prison, to slavery because they lusted after the 'leeks and garlic'. We are to leave the ways of the world behind and desire them no more. That is where the 'practise' comes in. God has already saved us through Jesus, but our lives, hearts, attitudes, behaviour need to express and reflect this new reality. It is a life of overcoming, just as it was for Jesus.

> I have told you all this so that you may have peace in me. Here on earth you will have many trials and sorrows. But take heart, because I have overcome the world. John 16:33

Yes, we have [escaped](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48090/what-is-the-meaning-of-therefore-all-died-in-2-corinthians-514/48096?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C8.0994#48096) - just as Israel did. Paul encourages us to STAY escaped and not fall back to old ways of slavery, lies and darkness. We will never realise the full measure of being free in this age because the Devil still roams, still deceives and is still head of this kingdom. He has been defeated and we are victors with Christ, but the time is not yet for Jesus to return and take the world back for the Father's glory and finish the process of perfection at that time.

> He who began a good work in you will carry it on to completion until the day of Christ Jesus. Phil 1:6

And 'because we *have* escaped, Paul encourages us to "partake" of this truth by being *active* participants, not static, ungrateful recipients only.

Comment: Good answer.  Israel had escaped Egypt and they still perished (almost all) in the desert.  These things are written as examples for us. 1 Cor 10:11.  +1

Answer (score 2):

**Have we already escaped the corruption that is in the world?**

**Having Escaped the Corruption: How?**

Jesus left an example for his followers to imitate, Christians by following his example and exercising faith in his ransom sacrifice have "escaped the corruption"in the world caused by evil lusts.

Titus 2:7-8 NASB

> In all things show yourself to be an example of good deeds, with
> purity in doctrine, dignified, 8 sound in speech which is beyond
> reproach, so that the opponent will be put to shame, having nothing
> bad to say about us.

Christians having escaped the corruption in the world caused by its evil desires, are to avoid pursuing immoral worldly desires, such as illicit sex, drug, and alcohol abuse, drunkenness, debase films and music, and violent sports like boxing.

Psalm 11:5 NASB

> 5 The Lord tests the righteous and the wicked, ***And His soul hates one
> who loves violence.***

**And how does it shape the meaning of the verse?**

What are "His precious and magnificent promises, " So that through them you may become partakers of the divine nature?

Jesus makes a covenant for a kingdom  with his anointed with spirit followers:

Luke 22:29-30 NASB

> 29 and just as My Father has granted Me a kingdom, I grant you 30 that
> you may eat and drink at My table in My kingdom, and you will sit on
> thrones judging the twelve tribes of Israel.

Jesus is going to heaven where his father is to prepare a place for  them.

John 14:2 NASB

> 2 In My Father’s house are many rooms; if that were not so, I would
> have told you, because I am going there to prepare a place for you.

Chosen to rule with him in his heavenly kingdom for a thousand years.

Revelation 20:6 NASB

> 6 Blessed and holy is the one who has a part in the first
> resurrection; over these, the second death has no power, but they will
> be priests of God and of Christ, and will reign with Him for a
> thousand years.

Partakers of the Divine nature granted immortality, incorruptibility [ Rom. 6:5, 1 Cor 15:42-54];

1 Peter 1:3-4 KJV

> 3 Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, which
> according to his abundant mercy hath begotten us again unto a lively
> hope by the resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead,4 To an
> inheritance incorruptible, and undefiled, and that fadeth not away,
> reserved in heaven for you,

**Conclusion**

Paul  is  also a fine example  to follow and strengthen Christians , having  escaped the corruption of the world with its evil desires  ,he urges  the partakers of the divine nature  [Heb 3:1 Partakers  of the heavewnly  calling  NASB] to endure to the end   and  so  benefit these magnificent promises. Such  as Immortality , incorruptibility,  live in heaven  and to rule as kings and priests [ Rev.20:6} with Jesus over the earth.

Comment: Not that I have already attained, says Paul, but I press on.

Comment: Mike Borden:  Yes, There is no other way to receive  God’s approval for salvation. We are in a race for life, and we must “run with endurance” until we cross the finish line.  Paul wrote. (Hebrews 12:1).  Tks

Comment: Paul also knew he was saved.

Comment: Being imperfect, Paul experienced a continual conflict between his mind and the sinful flesh. [Rom. 7:21-24] But he did not give up. He said: [1 Cor.9: 27 NASB} "but I strictly discipline my body and make it my slave, so that, after I have preached to others, I myself will not be disqualified." No one is saved unless he remains faithful to the end

Comment: Agreed.  And everyone who calls on the name of the Lord will be thus saved. Jude 1:24-25, 1 Thes 5:23-24. Paul did not discipline his body in the physical but in the Spirit (Gal 5:16) We must not trust that *we* have the ability to remain faithful to the end.  "Being confident of this very thing, that he which hath begun a good work in you will perform it until the day of Jesus Christ: - Phil. 1:6".  It is Christ in us that is the hope of Glory (Col 1:27) and I am not producing Christ in me, God is by the Holy Spirit because it is the Spirit that lusts against the flesh (Gal 5:17).

Answer (score 0):

**Have we already escaped the corruption that is in the world?**
Yes and No.

**NO:**
We are still in the world subject to corruption and death and we even sometimes sin.

**YES:**
We have already escaped the corruption that is in the world by being spiritually freed from its spiritual stain. We who are Christians have been united with Christ, his death, and resurrection. We are covenantally identified with him and are therefore marked for salvation, disassociated from our sins, and are numbered among those who will be saved on the Day of Resurrection and Judgment upon which we will have fully escaped from the corruption that is in the world and will be truly free to fully live for God with our whole being.